# SASS Multiplication with units

Tags: sass

If I try to multiply two value with units I get an unexpected error.

```
$test: 10px;

.testing{
  width: $test * $test;
}
result: 100px*px isn't a valid CSS value.
```

Comment: Look at [understanding-sass-units](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sass-units/).

Answer (score -8, accepted):

You cannot multiply two px values. Better way of doing it is function, but you have to use add in it to achieve it: -

```
$test: 10px;

@function calc-width($value1, $value2) {
  @return $value1 + $value2;
}

.testing {
  width: calc-width($test, $test);
}
```

Comment: Just for reference:  http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#number_operations

Comment: This is still adding, which does not meet the need to multiply presented by OP.

Comment: so your proposal is adding instead of multiplying?

Comment: This is incorrect, you [can simply multiply two px values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38324326/sass-multiplication-with-units/49951058#49951058) using interpolation. See my answer below.

Comment: This does not achieve what the question was asking.

Answer (score 48):

I have used [interpolation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_) in the past when I want to do math with variables, and I think it is the simplest solution. If this doesn't work for you, perhaps it is due to a difference in compilers?

```
$test: 10px;

.testing{
  width: #{$test * 2};
}
```

In fact `width: $test * 2;` compiles to `width: 20px` for me, you don't even need to use interpolation for simple math. I am using ember-cli-sass, which uses broccoli-sass-source-maps, which uses node-sass, which wraps libsass, to compile my SCSS to CSS. But it seems to work fine in [this jsbin](https://jsbin.com/figawawala/edit?html,css,output) which uses SCSS with Compass.

Where interpolation really helps is if you need to use `calc`.

```
$test: 10px;

.testing{
  width: calc(50% + #{$test * 2});  // results in calc(50% - 20px)
}
```

Answer (score 22):

**Multiplying units in SASS works like multiplying units in physics** / engineering / chemistry / [insert science here].

(see more about this at https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sass-units/)

Multiplying two pixel values, will get you px^2, which is an area, not a distance.

**What can you do?** If you are certain you will be multiplying pixels, use a function and divide by 1 pixel.

```
$test: 10px;

@function multiply-px($value1, $value2) {
  @return $value1 * $value2 / 1px;
}

.testing {
  width: multiply-px($test, $test);//100px
}
```

**If you don't know which units you'll be using in advance**, you can strip the units from $value2, such that you always get the units of $value1.

(read more on that at https://css-tricks.com/snippets/sass/strip-unit-function/)

```
$test: 10in;

@function strip-unit($number) {
  @if type-of($number) == 'number' and not unitless($number) {
    @return $number / ($number * 0 + 1);
  }

  @return $number;
}

@function multiply-use-first-unit($value1, $value2) {
  @return $value1 * strip-unit($value2);
}

.testing {
  width: multiply-use-first-unit($test, $test);//100in
}
```

Comment: Note that for `%` unit, you should divide for `100%`, not `1%`.

Comment: How do you use areas in css?

Comment: @BluE CSS doesn't support area units, so they're useless unless you're doing some sort of unit math within Sass itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
//try this

$test: 10;

.testing{
  width: $test * $test px;
}
```